# SQL query in Access

Tags: sql

Basically, I've been trying to make this query work for a while in Access and it's really frustrating me so instead of playing around with the criteria, I've decided to just do it in SQL instead but I can't quite figure out how to do this bit.

What I need to do is create a query that shows which members haven't returned an item that they're currently taking out on loan.  If possible I'd like to include a calculated field to state the date is was due back and how many days late it is.

The fields I'm using are as follows;

#### Table = Loan

```
Toy Name
Hire Date
Duration (in days)
Returned Date (if it hasn't been returned, the cell is blank)
```

#### Table = Toy

```
Purchase Price
Hire Price
```

Comment: If not returned, the cell is _blank_ (as an empty string), or `NULL`, which is a very different sort of blank?

Comment: Filter for 'Returned Date' is null

Answer (score 0):

you wrote:

```
a query that shows which members haven't returned an item
```

your table does not have members in it. secondly table toy have nothing related to toy like toy name or something. Please provide further detail of tables.
one more question what is the meaning of blank? Is it **Null** or blank string?

Comment: There is a 3rd table but none of the fields from the Members table is being used here so I assumed it was irrelevant.  Blank meaning Null, I apologise.  So if the toy has yet to be returned, the value in the cell is Null.

Comment: if we wont use member column then how do we know "which members haven't returned an item"

Comment: Member IDs have already been entered into the database, I just need a template to figure out how to go about this.  I'm guessing this query needs to search the "Returned Date" column for any Null values.  Then if it finds any Null values, it should return that row of data which will include the toy name, the memberID etc.